How to wrap tex around a shape?
I am making this document and want to wrap around this text to the circular arc, but I don't know how to do this. 
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[paperheight = 40cm, paperwidth = 60cm, margin=0.4cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} % remove page numbers

\begin{center} \begin{tikzpicture} 
        
        %Boundary
        \filldraw[color=black, fill=gray!10, very thick] (0,0) rectangle (59,39);
        
        %Circles
        \draw[very thick] (20.25, 19.5) circle (17); \fill[color=Aquamarine, opacity=0.2] (20.25,19.5) circle (17);
        \draw[very thick] (38.75, 19.5) circle (17); \fill[color=SeaGreen, opacity=0.2] (38.75,19.5) circle (17);
        
        % Title
        \node[annotation, font=, text width=8cm] at (5,37) {\begin{Huge} \textbf{U = Set Theory} \end{Huge}};
        
        % Right Area
        \node[annotation, centered, font=, text width = 16cm] at (59-13.75, 19.5) {
            \begin{Large} \textbf{Equivalence Relation} \end{Large} \\ \hspace{0.5cm} \\
            if $R$ induced by $A$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. \\ 
            Equivalence Class: $[a] = \{x: (a,x) \in R\}; \hspace{0.5cm} [a] \subseteq A$ \\
            Quotient Set, $A \backslash R = \{[a]: a \in A\}$ is always a partition of $A$ \\
            
            \hspace{0.5cm} \\ \hspace{0.5cm} \\
            
            \begin{Large} \textbf{Ordered Relation} \end{Large} \\ \hspace{0.5cm} \\
            Partial Ordering set: reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive \\
            Quasi Order set: irreflexive and transitive \\
            If $(S, \preceq)$ and $A \subseteq S$, then A is an ordered set of S. Hence relation of A induced by S is $R_A = R \cap (A \cross A)$\\
            Linearly ordered set: set s.t. all elements are comparable \\
            Ordered-Isomorphic Set: $A \simeq T$ if $f:S \leftrightarrow T$ is similarity mapping (if $a \preceq b$ then $f(a) \preceq f(b)$). \\ \hspace{0.5cm} \\
            
            Well ordered set: $S$ is an ordered set s.t. every subset has a first element. \\
            Union of such sets is non commutative. 
            The number of elements in such a set is known as its ordinal numbers and their algebra is non commutative. \\
            Well ordering theorem: every set can be well ordered \\ \hspace{0.5cm} \\
            
            Comparable elements: $a \nparallel b \iff a \preceq b$ or $b \preceq a$ \\
            Lexicographic order: if $b \not= b'$ then $(a,b) \prec (a',b')$ if $b \prec b'$ and if $b=b'$ then $(a,b) \prec (a',b')$ if $a \prec a'$ \\ \hspace{0.5cm} \\
            
            Hasse Diagram \\ \hspace{0.5cm} \\
            
            minimal element, $a \in S$ s.t. $\nexists x$ s.t. $x \preceq a$ while the maximal element, $a' \in S$ s.t. $\nexists x$ s.t. $x \succeq a$ \\ 
            first element, $a \preceq x \forall x \in S$ while the last element: $a \succeq x \forall x \in S$ \\
            limit element: $a \in S$ if $\nexists x$ s.t. $x \prec a$ and $a$ is not the first element. \\ \hspace{0.5cm} \\
            
            upper bound: $A \subseteq S$ and $M \in S$, then $M$ is the upper bound if $x \preceq M \forall x \in A$. Supremum is the largest upper bound. \\
            lower bound: $A \subseteq S$ and $m \in S$, then $m$ is the lower bound if $x \succeq m \forall x \in A$. Infimum is the largest lower bound. \\
            Initial segment: $a \in S$, then $S(a) = \{x: x \in S, x \prec a\}$ \\
            A is shorter than B if A is similar to an initial segment of B \\ 
            
            \hspace{0.5cm} \\ \hspace{0.5cm} \\
            
            \begin{Large} \textbf{Choice Function and Axiom of Choice} \end{Large} \\ \hspace{0.5cm} \\
            Choice function: if $\{A_i:i \in I\}$ is a non empty family of non empty subsets of X, then $\exists$ $f: \{A_i: i \in I\} \rightarrow X$ s.t. $f(A_i) = a_i \in A_i$ \\
            Cartesian Product: $\Pi \{A_i: i \in I\}$ is the collection of all choice functions defined on $\{A_i:i \in I\}$ \\
            Axiom of choice: There exists at least 1 choice function for non empty family of non empty sets \\
            Zomelo's Postulate: Let $\{A_i:i \in I\}$ be a non empty family of disjoint non empty sets then $\exists$ a subset $B$, s.t. $B \cap A_i = \{a_i\} \forall i \in I$ \\
            Zorn's Lemma: Let X be a non empty partial ordered set in which every chain has an upper bound \hspace{0.5cm} in X, then X contains at least 1 maximal element.
        };
            
\end{tikzpicture} \end{center}
    
\end{document}


Note that \parshape and \shapepar only work on single paragrpahs.

I was able to get this method working, but it limits the formatting. Like I can't center some text and I can't use display math. Is there any workaround which lets me freely format the text.

Welcome! Do you mean you used the linked thread to come up with a partial solution? If so, can you edit your question to use your current code?

You can also ask a new question using the code from the duplicate, with the new questions about centering and display math.
